# USB 3.0 to SAS; seems slow to me. Is it?

Tags: raid, sata, usb-3, sas

I've been transferring about 5TB from a USB 3.0 enclosure with built in hardware RAID running 4x SATA III drives. The destination is an external SAS enclosure (7x SATA II) with 2x SAS cables connected to PERC 6 card.

Its been going for over 2 days straight! It's only done about 2.5TB so far...

Wondering if this is normal? I'm using robocopy to do the copy.

and if this is normal; would using esata III be any better?

hope to hear your thoughts.
Thanks!

Comment: I have no idea how long this should take, but silly question - that USB 3.0 enclosure is actually on a USB 3.0 connection, right?  2.0 ports aren't forward compatible with the higher speeds.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/206370/how-is-disk-speed-measured-and-what-is-fast-how-long-should-a-copy-of-1500-gb-t

Comment: thanks for the response. Yes the USB3 enclosure is connected via USB3 cable to a new USB3.0 controller (pcie)

also FYI system resources are barely active via task manager. (4 core cpu running a almost nothing)

Thanks!

Comment: based on the above posted link I gather no my speeds are really slow. Their example is for USB2 and 1 disk however if anything it should be faster since I have 4 disks and USB3.
 

Thanks for the link, does anyone have any comments on how to speed this up?

Answer (score 0):

Try running a performance benchmark on each volume using [HDTune](http://www.hdtune.com/).  This may help you determine whether one of the disk subsystems is causing your poor performance.

The number of files can have a huge impact on performance.  Copying hundreds of thousands (or more) of small files will be much slower than copying a few thousand large files.

You mention you're using Robocopy, so I assume you're running Windows.  If you have a directories with many similarly-named files and you have 8.3 filename creation enabled, directory enumeration will be exponentially slower on those directories than if you [disable 8.3 filename creation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/121007).

Another possibility is that one or more disk in the source or target RAID is defective.  Even if you haven't had a catastrophic failure but have many reallocated sectors, the bad sector remapping will impact performance.  Run a long/extended diagnostic on each disk.